# KnockoutMVC with Kendo UI Complete for MVC can these be integrated server side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, knockout-mvc

Server side wrapper for knockout.js http://knockoutmvc.com/
and Server side wrappers for Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html
can these be integrated server side anyone done it or have a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can integrate Kendo controls using server side wrappers.

```
public static MvcHtmlString KEditorFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string name, string value)
{
    string ms = htmlHelper.Kendo().Editor()
            .Name(name)
            .Value(value)
            .ToHtmlString();

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(ms);
}
```

And in the view,

```
@Html.KEditorFor(model=>model.EditorValue, "EditorValue", Model.EditorValue)
```

I am not sure about *KnockoutMVC*, but you can do this for other *Kendo* controls, too.